select all rows from table A with table A.status=2 and all rows from table B where A.id=B.T1_id
I want select all rows from table A with status=2 and all rows from table B which column id from table A match with column T1_id from table B
table A



id
val1
val2
val3
status




1
aaa
430
40
1


2
bbb
760
45
2


3
ccc
650
90
1


4
ddd
680
30
1


5
eee
200
20
2



Table B



id
T1_id
TB_1
TB_2




1
1
a
aa


2
2
b
bb


3
2
c
cc


4
2
d
dd


5
3
e
ee


6
4
f
ff


7
5
g
gg


8
5
h
hh



and output is



val1
val2
val3
TB_1
TB_2




bbb
760
45
b
bb


bbb
760
45
c
cc


bbb
760
45
d
dd


eeee
200
20
g
gg


eeee
200
20
h
hh




You forgot to ask a question or explain why your attempts are not working. Plus your sample data does not match your desired output (ie, bbbb <> bbb). Have you researched JOIN?

This is a one-to-many join issue, so you should ask yourself is this is really what you want. But if it truly is what you want to see, then it's a simple join...
select 
 a.val1, 
 a.val2, 
 a.val3, 
 b.tb_1, 
 b.tb_2
from table_A a
join table_B b
  on a.id = b.t1_id
where a.status = 2




val1
val2
val3
tb_1
tb_2




bbb
760
45
b
bb


bbb
760
45
c
cc


bbb
760
45
d
dd


eee
200
20
g
gg


eee
200
20
h
hh



see fiddle

select *
from A
inner join B on A.Id=B.T1_Id
where A.status = 2

